# what is causing this xhtml error

Tags: apache, web, xhtml

I am attempting to make some alterations to a simple website, and to do so I've gone ahead and did a recursive wget in order to bring the entire website onto my machine (with permission). The original website is located at http://www.clubs.psu.edu/up/blockandbridle/index.xhtml and the copy of it that I have made is located at http://eatmyrice.org/blockandbridle/index.xhtml. Most everything seems to be working well, although for some reason I get the following error when I visit the copy of index.xhtml on my own server

[image]

I've compared the code between the two sites and as far as I can tell there are not any differences (although I've gone through and fixed links to point to the correct location) that would be causing this. Any help would be appreciated as im not sure what is causing this to happen, thanks (also in case it would make any difference, the copied site is running on an apache server, not sure what the original one is running on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both documents contain the same errors, which [are easily detectable with a validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Featmyrice.org%2Fblockandbridle%2Findex.xhtml&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). One document is HTML and is parsed by the browser's HTML parser. The other document is XHTML and is parsed by an XML parser. The browser is only exposing the error in XML mode.

```
david@raston ~ $ curl -I http://www.clubs.psu.edu/up/blockandbridle/index.xhtml | grep Content-Type
Content-Type: text/html
~ :
david@raston ~ $ curl -I http://eatmyrice.org/blockandbridle/index.xhtml | grep Content-Type
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml
```

Comment: thanks for the info, will have to use that validator in the future as well. do you know what would be causing that to happen? (one server serving it as html while the other is doing xhtml) both the index.html and index.xhtml file are identical other than the extensions

Comment: *Other* that the extensions? They appear to have the same extension. It is a matter of server configuration.

Comment: will have see what I can do in that case, do you think their server simply has xhtml support disabled? or could it be setup automatically server xhtml pages as html instead